# Propel is storing single quotes with backslash in MySQL even though magic_quotes are off

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I have checked both get_magic_quotes_gpc() and get_magic_quotes_runtime() in my PHP code, and they are not turned on, but I am still getting single quotes stored in MySQL as "\'" when using [Propel](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/propel/info).

I don't want to have to use stripslashes() if I can avoid it. Is there something that I am doing incorrectly here?

```
$emp = new Employers();
$emp->setCompanyname($companyname);
$emp->save();
```

*Joe's Company* is stored as *Joe\'s Company* in MySQL.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the values *before* you save them to the database?

Comment: I have never seen that happen before but yes, the postdata coming in already has the single quote escaped with a backslash. Very strange behavior. Does anyone know how to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Found the solution, seems that the WP site uses this silly feature. No other methods seem to be able to turn this off except the solution here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949768/with-magic-quotes-disabled-why-does-php-wordpress-continue-to-auto-escape-my and here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/stripslashes_deep

Comment: Does this answer your question? *[With "magic quotes" disabled, why does PHP/WordPress continue to auto-escape my POST data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949768/with-magic-quotes-disabled-why-does-php-wordpress-continue-to-auto-escape-my)*