# json_decode won't work without stripslashes (magic_quotes in WordPress)

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress, magic-quotes-gpc

On the client side, I'm working with array of JavaScript objects. On submit I need to send it to PHP with form and manipulate the data further on the server-side.

So when building or changing an array of objects on the JavaScript side, I'm saving it to hidden input. It is passes with the form as expected, but the problem is that `json_decode` returns `NULL` if I don't `stripslashes` before decoding it.

Magic Quotes are off as I use PHP > 5.5, and `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` always returns `FALSE`.

Why do I need stripslashes in this case, and will this be the case on any production server with magic quotes off?

P.S.: Currently I'm still working on a development environment on Windows and an [EasyPHP](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/EasyPHP) local server.

Posted data on server side looks like (`var_dump`):

I'm using WordPress as a container of my application.

```
string(5045) "[{\"address_components\":[{\"long_name\":\"Flughafenstrasse\",\"short_name\":\"Flughafenstrasse\"...
```

Comment: How exactly are you creating the JSON string?

Comment: @haim770 The object is basically google maps placeResult object with some modification (a pair of fields is added to object) and then I use `JSON.stringify` before saving the value to hidden input.

Comment: If you `console.log(json)` before appending to hidden input, are there any slashes?

Comment: @haim770 No, there are no slashes. When I read back from input and use `JSON.parse` the string is converted to the object (or array of objects) as it should be. So slashes are added when posting data to server via form.

Comment: And what about `console.log(hiddenInput.value)`, after you append to the hidden input?

Comment: @haim770 I checked that also, it's still normal. I've updated the question with example data as it looks on server side (after submitting). So the slashes are for sure added when posting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? *[With "magic quotes" disabled, why does PHP/WordPress continue to auto-escape my POST data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949768/with-magic-quotes-disabled-why-does-php-wordpress-continue-to-auto-escape-my)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application that I was working on was as a WordPress plugin, as it was integrated in WordPress. And it turns out that WordPress (as of current version: 3.8.1) adds slashes (quotes) to GET and POST data on load. And even with PHP > 5.4 and `get_magic_quotes_gpc` returning `0` data is still escaped.

The solution is simply to `stripslashes` if you use WordPress, but who knows when WordPress will disable such behaviour and your application will have issues again :)

Some links for the issue:

- [wp_magic_quotes()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_magic_quotes)
- [stripslashes_deep()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/stripslashes_deep)
- [Similar issue on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949768/with-magic-quotes-disabled-why-does-php-wordpress-continue-to-auto-escape-my)

Comment: That saved the day for me, been struggling for a couple of days with it. Great find!

Comment: The behaviour is still enabled in November 2019 (PHP 7.1.33 (2019-10-23) and WordPress 5.2.4 (2019-10-14)).