# json_decode returning "NULL" for POST data in WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I tried to `JSON.stringify` an array to the server like so:

**JavaScript:**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: ajax_url, 
    data: {
       'settings' : JSON.stringify([...]),
       'action'   : [...]
       },
    traditional: true,
    success:function(data) {
        alert("SUCCESS");
    }, 
    error: function(errorThrown){
       console.log(errorThrown); 
   } 
});
```

But when I tried `json_encode` it in PHP it returns `NULL`.

**PHP**

```
$param = json_decode($test, true);
var_dump($param); //it retuns NULL
```

And `JSON.stringify` array is displayed like this:

```
{\"uid\":{\"@cdata\":\"6\"},\"board_name\":{\"@cdata\":\"test\"},\"skin\":{\"@cdata\":\"default\"},\"use_comment\":{\"@cdata\":\"\"},\"use_editor\":{\"@cdata\":\"\"},\"created\":{\"@cdata\":\"20160307182421\"}}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Once upon a time, PHP decided it would be a good idea to escape quote marks in GET and POST parameters, to protect unwitting developers from SQL injection vulnerabilities. They called this sorcery, ["Magic Quotes"](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

When PHP saw the error in their ways, they decided to remove this feature, but for WordPress [the damage was already done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949768/with-magic-quotes-disabled-why-does-php-wordpress-continue-to-auto-escape-my).

WordPress had embraced the magic quotes from earlier versions, and had become dependent on the half-arsed security it provided. To this day, they continue to add-back the quote marks, so that you must explicitly remove them.

## TL;DR:

In WordPress, use [`stripslashes`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php):

```
$test = stripslashes($_POST['settings']);
json_decode($test, true);
```

Comment: Love the way you worded this haha!

Comment: And 1 hour of confusion and messing around with anything I could think of and finally I came upon this answer that ended my sorrow.  :)  Thank you!!