# Why is WordPress adding extra quotes to my code?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, unicode

I'm using WordPress and [Avada](https://www.wpcrafter.com/review/avada/), and suddenly, when I put in code, it automatically adds extra quotes when the page outputted.

If I use the code block element and type:

```
<span style="color:yellow;">Test</span>
```

it outputs as:

```
`<span style="”color:yellow;”">Test</span>`
```

I have no idea why it's doing it. I try typing it out, and I try pasting from [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) and other editors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949768 and https://trickspanda.com/remove-curly-quotes-wordpress/

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to tell me with this link. I don't know enough about php and this seems relating to building plug ins? I'm writing simple code. It was working fine before I updated my theme? Why would the theme cause something like this?

Comment: I still don't think this is the problem. it's not converting my quotes, its adding new ones. I've tried adding plug ins and adding in those snipets and they don't do anything

Comment: I noticed that those are the curly double quotes.  I tried it in one of my client sites and I don't get the same results.  You might try disabling some plugins and see if the effect goes away.

Comment: I tried all plug ins disable except for the Fusion Builder and I enabled that and they were there. But the fusion builder is what create the layout for my pages.

Comment: WordPress can create problems as in *[With “magic quotes” disabled, why does PHP/WordPress continue to auto-escape my POST data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949768)*, but the problem described here is (entirely) different.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem with WordPress 4.7.4 and Avada 5.1.5. Apparently this is bug in the Avada Code Block element and so far my only solution is to remove all double quotes entirely.

This is my code inside the Code Block:

```
<iframe width=100% height=400 frameborder=0 src=https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/streetview?key={my-google-API-key}&location=52.4943894,5.0766594&heading=210&fov=100 allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And this is the rendered version in HTML (Avada added the quotes):

```
<iframe width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/streetview?key={my-google-API-key}&location=52.4943894,5.0766594&heading=210&fov=100" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Comment: I will have to see if that works, I seem to remember trying that and I'm not sure it worked for me or not. Thank you.