# WordPress removes special characters from a HTML form submissions

Tags: php, wordpress, validation

In WordPress, when I try to insert some special characters into an input field and submit, it will automatically remove them. For example, if I insert `<hi` into a text box, WordPress will remove this word since there is a `<` character next to it. For example:

[image]

As you can see, in this case, WordPress has removed the word `<string>`. Following are the HTML and PHP codes I am using on my WordPress page.

```
<!--HTML code for the form-->
<form action="" method="post" target="_blank">
  <input type="text" name="user_input">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<?php 
  echo "Output: ".stripslashes_deep($_POST['user_input']);
?>
```

The same thing happens even if I get similar data from a database(with speicial charactors like `<string>`) and try to print it into a WordPress page. Is there a way to keep these special characters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent WordPress' default input sanitization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68104290/prevent-wordpress-default-input-sanitization)

Comment: This exact question was asked a few days ago.

Comment: @disinfor Thank you for the comment. No, that answer does not help me at all. I am using the `stripslashes_deep` to take care of the problem that question was having.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you're using. The bountied answer is what works. There is an answer using `stripslashes_deep` but it doesn't work - or doesn't work as expected.

Comment: You can also check out the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949768/with-magic-quotes-disabled-why-does-php-wordpress-continue-to-auto-escape-my

Comment: @disinfor Those answers do work for striping off backwards slashes. However, when I have a `<` character and a word next to it, it doesn't put a ` \\` in front of it and it just remove the whole word from been displayed. If I have a word like `5 <double`  in my database and if I use the line `echo $row['word'];` it will only display the value `5` on the screen. Your answer on `sanitize_text_field filter` is promising. But it didn't do anything when I put this code in my `theme's functions.php` file. Should it go somewhere else? Or is there a plugin I can download to insert this code?

Comment: _“If I have a word like `5 <double` in my database and if I use the line `echo $row['word'];` it will only display the value `5` on the screen.”_ - of course it will, because the browser thinks the rest is supposed to be a _tag_. Escape your data properly using the methods WP provides. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/#escaping-securing-output

Comment: @CBroe I didn't know about that and what you gave me is the answer. Thank you for this.